# Small change to User Model (not subclassing)...Bad Idea?

Tags: django, django-models

I know that it's a bad idea to touch the User Model directly.  You should instead extend it.  My issue is that I've already extended to a certain extent.  I wanted users to register/authenticate with their email address rather than a username.  To do so, I turned username into a hash value of their email address.

That worked out just fine.  My problem now is that my admin is a mess whenever I have a User ForeignKey.  The unicode method of a User model presents the username.  In my case, that's not ideal.  I'd much rather be able to see a first name or email so that I can manually look  things up at times.

My question is, can I just change the unicode method in the User model without getting in trouble? Is this trivial enough that it won't lead to future/current breakages?

Thanks

Comment: Why not try and test it? You could write some tests for the functionality you're looking to implement and for the other functionalities you fear you might break.

Comment: I figured this might be a common question.  If there's a better way or this is considered awful, I'd like to know.  I'm fairly new to django and I don't want to break my site

Answer (score 0):

Now that I'm rereading your question... Why not simply turn username into the email itself instead of hashing it?

Comment: username has a max_length of 30.  Some emails may be longer

Comment: Good point; I'll run into this problem one of these days myself then. Thanks :)